# Solution for a nonlinear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

During my PhD thesis im facing the following ODE:

$$\frac{C}{\gamma}\frac{f'(y)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(y))^2}}=y-K_1$$

Where $y$ is a positive variable$(y\geq0)$, $C$ and $\gamma$ are parameters, $K_1$ is a constant (due to previous integration and is necessarily $\leq0$) and $f'(y)=df/dy$  is the function I want to obtain. Squaring both sides, it can be rewritten:

$$(\frac{df}{dy})^2=\frac{\gamma^2(y-K_1)^2}{C^2-\gamma^2(y-K1)^2}$$

Now, if I guarantee that $C^2-\gamma^2(y-K1)^2 \geq 0$ the solution is easily obtained through:

$$df=\pm\frac{\gamma(y-K_1)}{\sqrt{C^2-\gamma^2(y-K1)^2}}dy$$

But my problem is that in many times this term in the square root will be less than 0, then i don't know how to proceed since the function will not belong to $\mathbb{R}$ anymore, which is phisically impossible in the problem. Could anyone help me in this matter?

Thank you very much!

P.S.: The ODE was obtained after integration of $\frac{Cf''(y)}{(1+f'(y)^2)^{3/2}}=\gamma$

Comment: Indeed if a solution exists to your ODE then $$0\le y-K_1\le\left\lvert\frac\gamma C \right\rvert$$ since $$\frac{f'(y)}{\sqrt{1+(f'(y))^2}}=g(f'(y))\in]-1,1[$$ (as $g(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$ has an image of $]-1,1[$ applied to $\mathbb R$.) So the term on the right-hand side at the end of your calculations must be positive more or less by assumption

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch You shoul post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let us re-write the ODE as
$$\frac{A y'(x)}{\sqrt{1+y'^2(x)}}=x-B \implies A^2 y'^2(x)=(x-B)^2(1+y'^2(x)).$$
$$\implies y'^2(x)(A^2-(x-B)^2)=(x-B)^2.$$
$$\implies y'(x)=\pm \frac{x-B}{\sqrt{A^2-(x-B)^2}}.$$
$$\int dy= \pm \int \frac{x-B}{\sqrt{A^2-(x-B)^2}}dx.$$
$$\implies y(x)=\pm \sqrt{A^2-(x-B)^2}+D$$
$$\implies (y-D)^2+(x-B)^2=A^2.$$
$D$ is constant of integration, $A=C/\gamma$, $B=K_1.$